# Style of edittext in API below 21

Tags: android

EditText in API 22 work perfect. Bup for example in API 19 it's seems bad. Will it has relation with gradle? 
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

In api 19
[image: api 19]

In api 22 all work perfect
[image]

xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_firstname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Логин*"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColorHighlight="#F14040"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="@style/Theme.App.Base"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:maxLength="13"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lastname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Пароль"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColorHighlight="#F14040"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    style="@style/Theme.App.Base"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    />
```

***EDIT***
it's my style file.

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.App.Base">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/myToolbarStyle</item>
        <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewMy</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/SearchViewMy</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="stateTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>

    </style>

    <style name="myToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    </style>
    <style name="SearchViewMy" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.SearchView">
        <item name="submitBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="queryBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please upload the style xml

Comment: @Lino I uploaded the style xml

Comment: i got the same problem just put the edittext inside a linearLayout and style the linearLayout

Comment: @FabioVenturiPastor it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is not depended on gradle.Instead of `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
use `android:layout_height="40dp"` a fixed height and check it again

Comment: Change your style to `<style name="Base">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it's also doesn't work. I notice that when I press tablayout tab and toolbar home button  they also became like edittext black

Comment: did you check on real device?

Comment: Yes I checked in real device problems remain